# How to add widgets dynamically after parent is created

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4, pyside

I'm trying to build an interface using custom widgets, and have run into the following problem.

I have a widget `Rectangle` which I want to use as an interactive element in my interface. To define a rectangle I just need to give it a parent, so it knows what window to draw itself in, and a position `[x,y, width, height]` defining its position and size. (I know that some of you will say "You should be using layouts as opposed to absolute positioning" but I am 100% sure that I need absolute positioning for this particular application).

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
import sys

class Rectangle(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args):
        super(self.__class__,self).__init__(parent)

        print parent, args
        #expect args[0] is a list in the form [x,y,width,height]
        self.setGeometry(*args[0])

    def enterEvent(self, e):
        print 'Enter'

    def leaveEvent(self, e):
        print 'Leave'

    def paintEvent(self, e):

        print 'Painted: ',self.pos
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
        painter.setBrush(QColor(200,100,100))
        painter.drawRect(0,0,self.width()-1, self.height()-1)
        painter.end()
```

I also have a `Window` widget which is the canvas on which my visualization is to be drawn. In the `Window`'s `__init__()` definition I create a **rectangle A** at 20,40.

```
class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()


        self.widgets = [Rectangle(self,[20,40,100,80])]
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.setGeometry(300,300,800,600)
        self.setWindowTitle('Window')
        self.show()

    def addWidget(self,Widget, *args):
        self.widgets += [Widget(self, *args)]
        self.update()

    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        for widget in self.widgets:
            print widget.geometry()
```

Since I am building a visualization, I want to create my `Window` and then add widgets to it afterwords, so I create an instance `mWindow`, which should already have **rectangle A** defined. I then use my window's `addWidget()` method to add a second rectangle at 200,200 - call it **rectangle B**.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app= QApplication(sys.argv)

    mWindow = Window()
    mWindow.addWidget(Rectangle, [200,200,200,80])
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The issue I have is that only **rectangle A** actually gets drawn.

I know that both **rectangle A and **rectangle B** are getting instantiated and both have `myWindow` as their parent widgets, because of the output of `print parent` in the constructor for `Rectangle`.

However, when I resize the window to force it to repaint itself, the `paintEvent()` method is only called on **rectangle A**, not **rectangle B**. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just forgot to show the rectangle. In `addWidget`, add this before `self.update()`:

```
self.widgets[-1].show()
```

The reason why you don't need `show` for the first rectangle object is because it is
created in the Window constructor. Then, Qt itself is making sure objects are properly
shown (which is misleading, I agree...).

Comment: Ah, that fixed it. To understand this more thoroughly, how is `.show()` called on widgets when you create them inside the parent widget's constructor? If I create a third rectangle after calling `self.show()` on my parent widget, it won't appear, so that makes me think that when you call `.show()` on the parent, it gets called on the child as well. However, if I put a `self.show()` call in `addWidget()` instead of `self.widgets[-1].show()` nothing happens.